# What's the best way to write an R function which test multiple conditions?

Tags: r

I'm writing a function in R which will solve an equation. I want it to work for all the different rearrangements of that equation. I want just one function so that I can alias it with different defaults.

For simplicity, assume I want to solve a = b/c, given 2 of these variables

```
my_fun <- function(a,b,c) {
    if(is.na(a)) {
        return(b/c)
    } else if(is.na(b)) {
        return(a*c)
    } else if(is.na(c)) {
        return(b/a)
    }
}

my_fun(a=NA,b=2,c=4)
> [1] 0.5
my_fun(a=NA,b=c(2,5),c=4)
```

This is clearly the wrong approach. Please can someone suggest a better way.

Comment: What is wrong with the approach? `2/4 = 0.5` was correct when I went to school :-o

Comment: I can't think of any good situation where you'd actually want to do this (treat arguments as interchangeable).

Comment: @hong-ooi I want to alias this function with different defaults which are relevant to different solutions. How would you approach this?

Comment: You should rethink how you're designing your code.

Comment: see the code for `seq.default` for an example of how to use arguments for multiple roles. Your head may explode.

Comment: `power.t.test` is another example.

Comment: I see what you mean re seq.default & power.t.test. I might just look for something more elegant :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a call for the `switch` function which provides facilities like that of `case` statements in other declarative languages. It can take either a numeric or a character result for the evaluation of the first argument `EXPR`. In the case of numeric results, the succeeding items in the argument list are evaluated. I think that the behavior of this implementation in throwing an error for either zero or more than one missing value is the desired result:

```
my_fun <- function(a,b,c) {stopifnot( which(is.na(list(a,b,c))) == 1,
                                        "Test for exactly one missing parameter")

             switch( which(is.na(list(a,b,c))), 
                                    b/c, 
                                    a*c, 
                                    b/a)}
 my_fun(a=NA,b=2,c=4)
#[1] 0.5

my_fun(a=NA,b=c(2,5),c=4)
#[1] 0.50 1.25

>      my_fun(a=NA,b=2,c=4)
Error: "Test for exactly one missing parameter" is not TRUE
```

The two values returned from the second call is to be expected in R due to argument recycling.

Comment: nice, although `navec <- is.na(list(a,b,c)); if (sum(navec)==0) stop("can't specify all three values"); if (sum(navec)>1) stop("informative error"); switch(which(navec)), ...)` might be better in the long run

Comment: Agreed: An informative error message would be better.And in this use case it would probably be  test of "==1" since the goal is to solve for the missing parameter.

Comment: @ben-bolker thanks. that looks very promising. I'd put in a test for != 1 missing, but your way is more elegant. I'll try it out.